# Removing the warning 'TelemetryConfiguration.Active is obsolete' in Azure application insights

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I updated my azure application insights and now I am getting the warning

```
'TelemetryConfiguration.Active is obsolete'
```

I currently have a method like this

```
static Load()
{
    var pchannel = new inMemoryChannel();
    .....
    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel = pchannel;
}
```

Do you think it will be safe to substitute

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel = pchannel;
```

with this

```
TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault().TelemetryChannel = pchannel;
```

This removes the warning.

Answer (score 3):

Since `TelemetryConfiguration.Active` is deprecated, in asp.net core app, we suggest to use `var newConfig = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();`

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1152).

Comment: do you think the substitution will be safe ?

Comment: We DO NOT recommend using `TelemetryConfiguration.Active` - instead we recommend using DI from `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. If not use DI,  create the configuration with `TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault()`. Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/pull/1148).